# How can I post to Tumblr an embedded video using the Tumblr API?

Tags: python, api, video, tumblr, embedded-video

I'd like to post a video to tumblr on behalf of the user using the [tumblr api](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) (after receiving its access token). It works fine with youtube/vimeo videos, but not when giving a specific video url (without actually uploading it from scratch), such as [this video](https://d22d7v2y1t140g.cloudfront.net/m_8386091_p64lvWa7cCG7.mov.mp4). I want my video to be playable on the tumblr dashboard (and in the user's blog).

I'm using the following endpoint: https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/postHere with these paramters:

```
params = {'type': 'video', 'caption': 'my cool video post!', 'embed': 'https://d22d7v2y1t140g.cloudfront.net/m_8386091_p64lvWa7cCG7.mov.mp4', 'format': "html"}
```

How can I do something similar for other types of videos?

Comment: Why can't you use [Video Posts](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#video-posts) with an HTML5 video/Flash embed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one recommended way, using the `pytumblr` external library:

```
import pytumblr
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    '<consumer_key>',
    '<consumer_secret>',
    '<oauth_token>',
    '<oauth_secret>',
)
# Now that you're established, look at the client.create_video method.
client.create_video(**kwargs)
```

For a further look into what params it takes, [see the source](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/master/pytumblr/__init__.py#L386), particularly the `data` value, which is a string of a local path to upload or the `embed` value, which is the section of HTML code which will load your externally hosted video.

For info on what the embed tag should look like, you can see it in the [response object of the example api](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#video-posts):

```
{
  "width": 250,
  "embed_code": "<object width=\"248\" height=\"169\"><param
     name=\"movie\" value=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/
     v\/4Q1aI7xPo0Y&rel=0&egm=0&
     showinfo=0&fs=1\"><\/param><param name=\"wmode\"
     value=\"transparent\"><\/param><param name=\"
     allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"><\/param><embed
     src=\"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/
     4Q1aI7xPo0Y&rel=0&egm=0&showinfo=
     0&fs=1\" type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\"
     width=\"248\" height=\"169\" allowFullScreen=\"true\"
     wmode=\"transparent\"><\/embed><\/object>"
```

}

Comment: Thanks! It works for flash videos. Two issues left: 1. In is not compatible on mobile (non-flash player..). 2. In the tumblr dashboard there is no thumbnail picture for the video. How can I fix that?

Comment: The example showed how to embed a flash player, but you could also embed an HTML5 video player. Here's an example: http://www.newbreedmarketing.com/blog/embed-html5-video#.UpJSSGTF2aU

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but not all video hosting sites provide thumbnails on Tumblr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481898/video-posts-with-auto-thumbnaillike-in-facebook-in-tumblr-com/17544279#17544279

Answer (score 1):

Below is parameter for video post in tumblr

```
$params = array(
   'type' => 'video',
   'caption' => 'caption',
   'embed'=> '<iframe 
                 width="560" 
                 height="315" 
                 src="you youtube url" 
                 frameborder="0" 
                 allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
                 allowfullscreen></iframe>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the video file from your server by embedding an HTML5 video like this:

```
$params = array(
   'type' => 'video',
   'caption' => 'caption',
   'embed'=> '<video width="100%" height="auto" controls><source src="/path/to/video" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>'
);
```