# Embedding HTML5 video in Tumblr (dashboard and blog)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, video, tumblr

Bit curios about the possibility to embed a custom HTML5 video player into Tumblr.
How it works now is basically that you put in an URL or embed code to Youtube or any other service and it'll load up the video and show it in the dashboard feed and on your blog.

I just checked with Vimeo, and in that case it seems like it fetches a vimeo iframe with the video (I guess it's their embed code) and inject it into the DOM when the play button is pressed.

Would it be possible to mimic this behaviour with a custom iframe of my own? Make Tumblr accept my own embed code (iframe based) that leads to a HTMl5 video and also serve up a preview image before the video is actually played.

So when I'd input for example, `www.mydomain.com/video1` it would recognize it as a video and have it behave like any other video service out there.

Or would it otherwise be possible to do via their API?

Just to clarify: I would not want to use the Tumblr HTML5 video player, but a player of my own chosing.

Comment: Hey, I wasn't 100% sure if tumblr would disable iframe content from unknown hosts (ie not youtube, vimeo, etc) but I just created a post with html that contains an iframe to another website. Do you have an example of a video site that has content that tumblr claims not to support? Thanks

Comment: @lharby Oh, right, didn't test that yet. But was the content available via the dashboard? Also, you're making a text post (I suppose), I want to be able to do this with native video post so it's easily rebloggable. Here's a list with video providers that doesn't support video thumbnails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481898/video-posts-with-auto-thumbnaillike-in-facebook-in-tumblr-com/17544279#17544279

Comment: I'm also a bit curios as it seems the dashboard only allow certain domains to be able to play inline? (Vimeo and Youtube for example) but not everyone from that list (in my previous comment) will show a play button, but a button that shows you'll be taken to a new page, this happens for blip.tv and metacafe for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tumblr dashboard will only play video previews for Video Posts. Anything embed in a caption or body will not get the preview treatment.

AFAIK, the only way to get a custom video to have a preview would be for Tumblr to work with your own platform / API. Tumblr pulls in the preview thumbs when you make the Video Post, if they support the platform.

There is a list of tested video platforms / providers here: [Video Posts with Auto Thumbnail(Like in Facebook) in Tumblr.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481898/video-posts-with-auto-thumbnaillike-in-facebook-in-tumblr-com)

Comment: Mm, I'm wondering if they have some sort of special treatment for those sites, a whitelist for trusted sources. Otherwise I could just check what javascript a vimeo iframe supplies for example, and then just copy whatever they serve up.

Comment: I am almost positive Tumblr pulls in the preview images server side, based on the video provider and its not possible to force it.

Comment: Bad news then :( I suppose that's the most logical reasoning though

Answer (score 0):

OK

So on this tumblr the 3 posts along the top are ones I have tried.

http://nativecitizenstest.tumblr.com/

First is a Video type post but simply passing the url to tumblr.

Second is a text post but passing custom embed html from vine (this included a script which I did not know would work).

Third is a text post with an iframe in that I hand coded.

I think metcalf seems to be flash video and I don't know if that is supported, but a little googling should tell us.

Comment: Interesting, did not expect Vine to work like that. But still, it's not showing anything in the Tumblr dashboard..