# Meta tags for passing video content to Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

When you paste a Youtube or Vimeo link into Tumblr the post automatically populates with the video embed code and title.

We have a site that has video content through JWPlayer and have given the page open graph tags but the page doesn't populate. Does Tumblr support Open Graph tags for video or do you need to be whitelisted?

Comment: I feel the question needs more detail. What do you mean by *passing video content to Tumblr*? Does this relate to the dashboard, post creation or themes?

Comment: Thanks @Ben. In these case I believe that Tumblr need to whitelist and add support for your domain to enable the population. I would try support@tumblr.com for more advice. More info on whitelisted domains: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17544279/2312574

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding HTML5 video in Tumblr (dashboard and blog)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759125/embedding-html5-video-in-tumblr-dashboard-and-blog)