# How do I add a "preview image" for an embedded iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tumblr

I have created a platform called [Animake It](https://animakeit.com) (the background images are links, and it only works on webkit/blink rendering engines). Animake It makes it easy to create an animated collage using content from around the web, and then optionally animating said content using a novel system that I built ([video here if you care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tL06lRCVoi4)).

The output of the editor (as you can see if you follow the links from the homepage) is a live animated system of images that get loaded in over time. Each creation comes with an embed code that lets you put it anywhere. [Here is an example of a Destructoid themed animated collage embedded into a tumblr blog](http://animakeit.tumblr.com/) (as a video post).

It takes a little while for the Animake It "player" (as in what's embedded in Tumblr above) to load, after which the animation starts. I'd like to make it feel more like a proper player, and add a play button along the lines of a youtube/vimeo video. Is there any way to create something that Tumblr and other blog services would understand as a video type?

Additionally, on Tumblr (and I'm guessing other services?), the embed code currently does not work for the dashboard or edit views in Tumblr. Instead, I see this in my Dashboard:

[image: Dashboard Tumblr View]

and this in the edit view (pressing play doesn't do anything):

[image: Dashboard Edit View]

Is this all functionality that I need to build myself using JavaScript, or are there different HTML meta tags that I can use to make this process easier? Is there anything that I might be potentially overlooking that is worth keeping in mind?

Best, and thanks,
Sami

Comment: For Tumblr, this is kinda related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481898/video-posts-with-auto-thumbnaillike-in-facebook-in-tumblr-com/17544279#17544279 tl;dr Tumblr would have to do the work. :(

Comment: I'm not so sure - the post you linked to makes it sound like the platform needs to provide the URL to the thumbnail preview, not Tumblr. Maybe I am mistaken, but it reads that way to me...

Comment: To clarify, AFAIK only Tumblr can integrate previews / playing on the dashboard, its not something you can set up alone. Also clarified the linked answer with Tumblr's role.

Comment: Sweet thanks! I'll get in touch with them sometime. I'll update this here if I get a response!